# How to handle an error in the middle of a chained IO?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a `readEnv` function that reads two env vars and returns an Either value, with a `ReadError` type as the Left value:

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception (SomeException(..), handle, throw)
import Data.Typeable (typeOf)
import System.Environment (getEnv)

data ReadError
  = MissingHost
  | MissingPort
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  eitherEnvs <- readEnv'
  case eitherEnvs of
    Left err -> print err
    Right (port, host) -> print (port, host)

readEnv :: IO (Either ReadError (String, String))
readEnv = do
  port <- getEnv "HOST"
  host <- getEnv "PORT"
  return $ Right (port, host)

readEnv' :: IO (Either ReadError (String, String))
readEnv' = handle missingEnv readEnv

missingEnv :: SomeException -> IO (Either ReadError (String, String))
missingEnv (SomeException e)
  | isMissingHost e = do
    print e
    return $ Left $ MissingHost
  | isMissingPort e = do
    print e
    return $ Left $ MissingPort
  | otherwise = throw e
  where
    isMissingHost e = take 4 (show e) == "HOST"
    isMissingPort e = take 4 (show e) == "PORT"
```

Since I know `getEnv` is an IO that will throw if the env var is missing, (i know there is lookupEnv, but my question is about how to handle error, not how to avoid error), I made a `readEnv'` function that will catch the IO Exception and converts it to the `ReadError` type.

The above code works, however, I don't like this pattern/style to handle exception, because in order to handle the exception from `getEnv "HOST"`, I have to put the handler outside of the entire `readEnv`, and parse the error message in order to distinguish if the error is `MissingHost` or `MissingPort`. If the error message doesn't contain "HOST" or "PORT", then the `missingEnv` can't distinguish which `getEnv` call is the exception from.

Ideally, there is a way to handle the exception at where it happened and short circuits to return with the Left value. Since I know the only IOException in `getEnv "HOST"` is `MissingHost` error, then I don't need to parse the error message.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Considered using an ExceptT monad and adding the right abstraction to `getEnv`.

For example:

First let's get past the boilerplate:

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception (SomeException(..), handle, throw)
       -- N.B. Should use Control.Exception.Safe
import qualified Control.Exception as X
import Data.Typeable (typeOf)
import qualified System.Environment as Env
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
```

We want to define something like IO but specialized to handling exceptions in a more composable manner and at least allow `getEnv`.  The monad is ExceptT IO:

```
type MyIO a = ExceptT ReadError IO a
runMyIO :: MyIO a -> IO (Either ReadError a)
runMyIO = runExceptT
```

And the operations we can perform in the monad should be lifted - remember, if the rest of your code is typing `lift` a lot then you might not have your monad properly abstracted.

```
getEnv :: String -> MyIO String
getEnv s = ExceptT ((Right <$> Env.getEnv s) `X.catch` hdl)
 where hdl :: X.SomeException -> IO (Either ReadError String)
       hdl _ = pure $ Left (Missing s)
```

Now we can use this version of `getEnv` in main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  eitherEnvs <- runMyIO ( (,) <$> getEnv "HOST" <*> getEnv "PORT" )
  case eitherEnvs of
    Left err -> print err
    Right (port, host) -> print (port, host)
```

And yes, we did redefine the Error type:

```
data ReadError
  = Missing String
  -- N.B an enum strategy such as MissingPort is doable but often has a
  -- data-dependency at the call site such as @getEnv "host" MissingHost@
  --
  -- That would be a lot like your 'missingEnv' function which forms a mapping
  -- from user strings to the ADT enum 'ReadError'.
  deriving (Show)
```

Comment: I see. The idea is to wrap the getEnv function and handle the exception there. I think can still be done without using ExceptT tho.

Comment: It can.  I'd say the idea is to catch and wrap exceptions at the granularity of the error messages you desire. For example, you could derive `Exception` for `ReadError`, catch/discard the old exception and throw a more informative one from there and all in IO.  I went a step further and avoided re-throwing with exceptions since that is rarely what I personally desire.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lookupEnv` really isn't that bad. The following provides the same locality of error handling as Thomas M. DuBuisson's answer.

```
module Main where

import System.Environment (lookupEnv)

data ReadError  = MissingHost | MissingPort deriving (Show)

type EnvReadResult a = IO (Either ReadError a)

main :: IO ()
main = readEnv >>= either print print

parseEnv :: String -> ReadError -> EnvReadResult String
parseEnv name err = lookupEnv name >>= return . maybe (Left err) Right

readEnv :: EnvReadResult (String, String)
readEnv = do 
             host <- parseEnv "HOST" MissingHost -- host :: Either ReadError String
             port <- parseEnv "PORT" MissingPort -- port :: ditto
             return $ (,) <$> host <*> port  -- Combine and lift back into IO
```

`parseEnv` takes a variable name and the error to report if the variable is undefined, and returns an `IO`-wrapped `Either` value. The `maybe` function acts as the "exception handler", rewrapping a `Just` value with `Right` or converting `Nothing` to an appropriate `Left` value.

The `Applicative` instance for `Either` effectively returns the first error found, or combines all `Right` values into a single `Right` value. For example:

```
 (,) <$> Right "example.com" <*> Right "23456" == Right ("example.com", "23456")
 (,) <$> Left MissingHost <*> Right "23456" == Left MissingHost
 (,) <$> Right "example.com" <*> Left MissingPort == Left MissingPort
```

---

You can also take advantage of the fact that applicative functors compose.

```
readEnv = let host = parseEnv "HOST" MissingHost
              port = parseEnv "PORT" MissingPort
          in getCompose $ (,) <$> Compose host <*> Compose port
```

In particular, since `IO` and `Either ReadError` are both applicative functors, so is `Compose IO (Either ReadError)`.

Comment: I agree `lookupEnv` is better. I just used `getEnv` as an example to learn how to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

With the above two answers, I come up with a solution that

1) Doesn't require additional complexity (ExceptT)

2) Doesn't need to parse the error message to distinguish which action failed.

3) readEnv is kept flat.

```
module Main where

import Control.Exception (IOException, handle)
import System.Environment (getEnv)

data ReadError
  = MissingHost
  | MissingPort
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  eitherEnvs <- readEnv
  either print print eitherEnvs

getEnv' :: String -> ReadError -> IO (Either ReadError String)
getEnv' env err = handle (missingEnv err) $ Right <$> (getEnv env)

readEnv :: IO (Either ReadError (String, String))
readEnv = do
  eitherHost <- getEnv' "HOST" MissingHost
  eitherPort <- getEnv' "PORT" MissingPort
  return $ (,) <$> eitherHost <*> eitherPort

missingEnv :: ReadError -> IOException -> IO (Either ReadError String)
missingEnv err _ = return $ Left err
```